# How can I change my buttons shape in carousel from lines in round

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, frontend, carousel

I want to change those indicators from carousel in round

I tried the code below and many others, not even one worked. Only was changed a little in round corners.

```
.carousel-indicators li {
  border-radius: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background-color: #404040;
}

<div class="container">
      <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data- ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="img/Background.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="img/Layer_4.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="img/Layer_5.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
  </div>
```

I need this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGuJu.jpg

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you're looking to change the bullet of the list item?

You'll want to use a un-ordered list<ul> instead of an ordered list <ol>. So make that change in your HTML.

```
<ul class="carousel-indicators">
   <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
   <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
   <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ul>
```

Then change your CSS to this:

```
.carousel-indicators li {
  list-style-type: circle;
}
```